# updating $PATH and rvm

Tags: ruby, rvm

I want to add the `~/bin` folder to my $PATH but everytime I do this and I the use rvm, I get the following warning:

> Warning! PATH is not properly set up,
>   '/Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin' is not at first place,
>            usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
>            it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
>            to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.1.2'.

I have tried reinstalling rvm with:

```
rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
```

But the warning still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to add the ~/bin folder to my $PATH but everytime I do this

And for some reason, you decided that the details of how you are trying to do that are unimportant?  Your question is equivalent to asking: I'm trying to output the string "Hello world!" but every time I run my progam, I get an error.

It *sounds like* you are trying to add ~/bin to the front of the PATH environment variable.  Well, why do you think you have to add ~/bin to the front?  Why not add it to the end?  Open up .bashrc, or equivalent, and add the following line at the top of the file:

```
PATH="${PATH}:~/bin"
export PATH
```

Comment: @dagda1, You can even add ~/bin to the front of your PATH as long as you do it before rvm adds its directories to the front of the PATH.  On my system, .bash_profile always executes before I open any terminal window, and inside .bash_profile I have some code that executes .bashrc.  So I know the order in which every statement that adds to the PATH in those two files will execute.  I use rvm too, so I make sure the rvm lines that add directories to the front of the PATH execute after all other additions to the PATH.  See: http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinstall, instead fix your PATH.

Run this at the command-line to see your PATH:

```
echo $PATH
```

It should list the ~/.rvm path first. If it doesn't then somewhere, in one of your ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile or ~/.profile files your PATH is being manipulated, and RVM's directory is getting buried.

This should be the last line to modify your path:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

This is somewhat like your PATH should look:

```
/home/ttm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/home/ttm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/bin:/home/ttm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/home/ttm/.pyenv/shims:/home/ttm/.pyenv/bin:/home/ttm/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/home/ttm/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.18.1/bin:/home/ttm/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/opennms/bin:/home/ttm/.rvm/bin
```

The [RVM installation page](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) has troubleshooting tips. It's worth reading.